# Oracle unable to extend index but I have many space free

Tags: oracle, index

I have application using Oracle database, and when I'm trying to call my pl/sql function which inserts many rows in tables I get an error:

```
unable to extend index MY_INDEX by 128 in tablespace MY_TABLESPACE
```

I use this query to get free space in my tablespace:

```
select round(sum(bytes)/1024/1024 ,2) as free_space 
from dba_free_space 
where tablespace_name ='MY_TABLESPACE';
```

And it returns me that I have about 40gb free.
What is the problem?

```
df -h
```

on my server says me that I have few Tb left, so it's not the problem either.

Result of this query is :

```
select * from dba_ts_quotas


TABLESPACE_NAME USERNAME            BYTES       MAX_BYTES BLOCKS MAX_BLOCKS DROPPED
TOOLS          PERFSTAT             3177054208  -1        387824 -1     NO
SYSAUX         APPQOSSYS            262144      -1        32     -1     NO
MY_TABLESPACE  MY_USER              7035027456  -1        858768 -1     NO
SYSAUX         AUDSYS               233963520   -1        28560  -1     NO
SYSAUX         GSMADMIN_INTERNAL    2293760     104857600 280    12800  NO
SYSAUX         FLOWS_FILES          524288      -1        64     -1     NO
MY_DATA        MY_DATA_USER         4343726080  -1        530240 -1     NO
```

Comment: I updated question with the data from dba_ts_quotas

Comment: sure, the result is about 39800, glad you're trying to help me

Comment: Are you sure you're not simply exhausting the free space with your "many data"? Try to scale things down and insert only one 10th and see if it works then.

Comment: Can you check if your data files are not just full and have not autoextend?

Comment: How can I check if they are full? (autoextend is set to NO)

Comment: Check dba_data_files (joining with dba_free_space.tablespace_name) to see which files are used by your tabalespace. Then check the filesystem using "df -h" as normal. Also, check the next, initial and pct_increase values on your tablespace ... pct_increase compouded over a number of extents can results in very large growth.

Comment: but if I have 40gb free in my tablespace, and enough free space in my hdd, what the problem can be?

Comment: Since you have lots of disk space left, your best bet is probably to add another datafile as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768920/

Comment: It might help to know how large the next extent needs to be and figure out what the largest contiguous space is. If you set pct increase on any table or index, you will eventually end up with extent sizes that don't fit into any open space in the data files. Try running this query to see if you have anything set with pctincrease: select owner, SEGMENT_TYPE, NVL(PCT_INCREASE, 0) PCT_INCREASE, count(*) from dba_segments where NVL(PCT_INCREASE, 0)>0 group by owner, SEGMENT_TYPE, NVL(PCT_INCREASE, 0) order by 1,2;